# Can I use Android data-binding with Maven?

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

There's a [beta release of a data-binding library by Google](https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html). According to the docs

> To use data binding, Android Plugin for Gradle 1.3.0-beta1 or higher is required.

In my project I need to use Maven instead. I'm trying to set up a minimal initial project. The problem is that the new data-binding library somehow mangles processing of the XML layout file that generates the R class and probably requires a gradle plugin: `android/databinding/tool/DataBinderPlugin`

There is no information on how to handle this without Gradle. Does anyone know what needs to be done to make this run with Maven as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There hasn't been a lot of effort put into this since most developers use gradle. That said, I did a quick bit of development to try to enable make builds that you could try out. There is a class android.databinding.tool.MakeCopy that you can try to run. It is a command line interface that copies resources from one or more directories to a target directory, modifies the layout files, and generates some artifacts that are required by the annotation processor (xml files, source files).

It should be included in the library with the annotation processor. You'll have to work out the full class path requirements to get it to work. As I said, I didn't spend a lot of time getting it going because we didn't have any clients for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hints. I found your MakeCopy class in the sources/android-MNC of the SDK, but the artifacts available from jcenter don't contain it. Is there a snapshot repo where I can find the library, or are there any instructions on how to build from source?

Comment: I managed to create a maven plugin that does what MakeCopy does. Now the question remains where to put the output files (src-out-dir, xml-out-dir, res-out-dir) so they get picked up? I'll accept your answer since it helped me a lot already.

Comment: Maybe describing their use will help. The source out directory must be picked up during the java compile stage (of your app) to trigger the annotation processor. The XML out directory is placed in an annotation of the generated source to be read during the annotation processor stage of compilation. The target res dir is where resources will be copied to and should be picked up by aapt. i.e. your app should point to this directory instead of the original (source) directory.

Comment: Again thanks for the hints! It took me one step further.The problem I'm stuck with now is getting the DataBindingUtil. It's supposed to be in com.android.databinding:library-1.0-rc1 which I cannot find in jcenter. I found a local maven repostitory in the SDK, but it only contains javadoc and sources. Can you help me understand how this library is added in the gradle build? I did a test project with Android Studio and found it in the build intermediates. Is it supposed to be modified and compiled during the build, or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: OK, it works now. My first Maven based databinding app is running on my phone. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @monacotoni Could you put more light into the subject plase? I d like to add MsBuild plugin for Xamarin.Android. Thanks

Comment: @moljac as I mentioned to you via mail, I'm not using it anymore, because it's missing important features, and I don't recall what had to be done to make it work. If you can extract the info from the old demo I sent you, it would be nice to share the info here.

Comment: Thanks. We are working on this as a side project and as soon as we'll have some results we'll share it here.
Danke/Thanks